# WSO2 ESB -Xml to JSON with xsi:nil=true

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

How to convert xml elements to json with xsi:nil=true.

Example:

XML:

```
<Element1>10</Element1>
<ELement2 xsi:nil=true/>
```

JSON:

```
{
    Element1: 10,
    Element2: null
}
```

I am using PayloadFactory to generate json.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use data mapper mediator [1] for XML to JSON conversion. For custom mapping you can use the UI of WSO2 Developer Studio ESB tool [2]

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Data+Mapper+Mediator

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Using+Data+Mapper+Mediator+in+WSO2+ESB

Comment: xsi:nil=true indicates that the field is null and empty.

DataMapper returns error for empty fields:

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String

Answer (score 0):

If you set the

```
 synapse.commons.enableXmlNilReadWrite=true
```

property in the synapse.properties file (stored in the <EI_HOME>/conf/ directory), XML elements where the 'nil' attribue is set to true will be represented in JSON as null objects as shown below.

```
{"object":null}
```